# Google App Engine tools

Tags: node.js

Once the email arrives to inbox, your google app engine program will need to read it using IMAP.
I do this with node

```
            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'Gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: 'your_email@gmail.com',//your gmail account
                    pass: 'password'//password
                }
            });
            var mailOptions = {
                from: 'Fred Foo ✔ <your_email@gmail.com>', // sender address 
                to: 'some@gmail.com', // list of receivers 
                subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line 
                text: 'Some Example ✔', // plaintext body 
                html: '<b>Here is a some version ✔</b>' ,// html body 
                attachments: [
                    {
                        filename: file_name,
                        path: file_name,
                        cid: 'unique@kreata.ee' 

                    }]
            };

            // send email with defined transport object 
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                if(error){
                    return console.log(error);
                }
                console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);

            });
```

Can someone advise something?

Comment: Can you explain what the code does?

Comment: Once the email arrives to  inbox , I need to read it with using google App Engine tools...